# ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT not working on MIUI

Tags: android

I want to use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT on my Xiaomi Device. I tried 
[this google sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-DirectorySelection), but it also not working. With code below i can normally run on Samsung galaxy s4.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 42);
```

Im getting "android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE }" error.

Comment: What version of Android is your device running? `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` was added in API Level 21 (Android 5.0).

Comment: @CommonsWare xiaomi mi4c with miui 7 based on android 5.1.1

Comment: Is there any workaround about this issue? no way to open the document tree in such devices? Got a report of the same problem on a Meizu m2 running Android 5.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Xiaomi screwed up, apparently. AFAIK, they're not Google Play certified, so they do not need to pass the CTS. There is nothing you can really do about it, other than to detect this case (e.g., use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()`, or catch the `ActivityNotFoundException`) and fall back to whatever you do on pre-Android 4.4 devices.

Answer (score 3):

I saw the same error occur on Xiaomi MI 6X with Android 10.

Upon some digging I realized that some devices allow the user to disable the "Files" app from Google Play Services (or might even do that by default). Thus, I would recommend first prompting user for enabling "Files" app and/or updating the Google Play Services. Please note, that on most devices the "Files" app is hidden from the user, thus it will not be present on app list in preferences.

Comment: Hi @jure-sencar I got the same issue reported for my [sftp server app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.becke.sftp_server__s0_v1) on an Android TV Mi Box 4/s and even could reproduce the issue on an emulated Android TV device, Android Pie 9.0 API 28.
Could you solve the issue on Xiaomi MI 6X and how? Unfortunately I could not find much evidence on "enabling "Files" app and/or updating the Google Play Services" can you maybe provide more information? Thank you.